# Orientdb limit geospatial index

Tags: indexing, lucene, geospatial, orientdb, orientdb2.2

`OrientDB` have a limit for the number of lines for `geospatial` index?

I make two same DB, but one with an index of my `geospatial` property

```
CREATE INDEX Ixy ON TabIndex (xy) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE;
```

For the same query I have:

90124 results (for the BD with no index).

82143 results (for index). I lost 7981 good results.

For a small DB i have the same result but not on a base with 100000 lines. Someone know why?

Comment: Hi John do you have a test case for this?

Which query did you use?

Comment: I query this: Select from TabIndex where ST_WITHIN(xy,'POLYGON ((0 0, 90 0, 90 90,0 90, 0 0))') = true

Comment: Can you provide al least a couple of records that do to return with that query and the index created?

Comment: My tab is a; id (int unique), idTag(int) tagName (String), xy (Opoint), z (double), type (String). when my tab is under 58000 lines the result is good after I loose some lines.

Comment: to create it I create a CSV and I use a json but when I index other property I have any problem. My CSV : id;id_tag;tag_name;xy;z;date;type;z2
0;749;tag749;POINT(35 60);35;2012-10-5 3:1:20;Personne;60

Comment: I find the problem, when the result from the index is major of 10000 or something like that it make a problem. (something limit to this value on the code) a patch will correct this problem in version 2.2.22 (orientdb developer source)